# Should we leave specifics questions open if there's a more generic answer available?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, review-audits

I just failed an audit while voting to close this [question about self-closing tag in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300986/aurelia-self-closing-require-element-does-not-work) as a duplicate of this [question about self-closing tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).

The answer to the first question does explain the relation between Aurelia and HTML, but if this question should remain open, it means that we'll probably end up with a duplicate question for every system relying on HTML tags.

Knowing that, should we leave specifics questions open if there's a more generic answer available?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The first question is specifically about custom elements (in this case, `require`), whereas the second is specifically about  elements defined in HTML5. It does not take into account custom elements (foreign elements are defined as [those from MathML and SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements))